# method not returning correct value

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have a method to check if the user wants to play another game, the problem is that if the user enters an invalid input then after a correct input `anotherGame` is still set to `Y`

When it exits the method the value of `anotherGame` is still `Y` even if they select `N` if they enter an incorrect input

When this block of code runs `anotherGame` is returning `Y` no matter what.

```
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid input (Y/N) only!");
     promptRedo(anotherGame);
}
```

**CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string anotherGame = "y";
        while (anotherGame == "y")
        {
            anotherGame = promptRedo(anotherGame);
            Console.WriteLine(anotherGame);
        }
    }
    static String promptRedo(String anotherGame)
    {
        Console.Write("Would you like to play another game? (Y/N) => ");
        String input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        if (input.Equals("y"))
        {
            anotherGame = "y";
        }
        else if (input.Equals("n"))
        {
            // get any key from user to exit program
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            anotherGame = "n";
            Console.WriteLine(anotherGame);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid input (Y/N) only!");
            promptRedo(anotherGame);
        }
        return anotherGame;
    }
}
```

Comment: `method not returning correct value` <== this is incorrect, The compiler doesn't just pick favorites, its doing exactly what you are telling it to do. The first thing you need to do is debug your code with breakpoints, then you will figure it out

Comment: @George I would rather go with Mauricio answer, as it's cleaner code ... remember you are already calling `promptRedo()` in your while loop, so no need to call it again and again insite your `promptRedo()`. Just remove the `promptRedo(anotherGame);` from your `promptRedo()` function, as it will exit and call it again through the `while` loop.

Comment: @lucumt the string `==` operator in C# does the same as `.Equals()`.  there's no need to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid input (Y/N) only!");
     promptRedo(anotherGame);
}
```

In this code you are just calling promptRedo() and returning anotherGame at the end of function. But you are supposed to return from promptRedo().

> Your code must be like below

```
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid input (Y/N) only!");
     return promptRedo(anotherGame);
}
```

Comment: or `anotherGame = promptRedo(anotherGame);` would accomplish the same on this case, and better yet, the same can be accomplish removing that line completely, as there's a `while` loop that will call the same method

Comment: minimal changes would be delete the entire line ;) = cleaner code, better understandable, no inner loops, better coding tips...

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need the recursive call, all you need to do is to remove

```
promptRedo(anotherGame);
```

From the else section inside `promptRedo` function.

Answer (score 1):

This function does not need an argument to be passed. instead of calling function again and againg just put it in a loop:

```
static String promptRedo()
{ 
    String anotherGame = ""
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Would you like to play another game? (Y/N) => ");
        String input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        if (input.Equals("y"))
        {
            anotherGame = "y";
        }
        else if (input.Equals("n"))
        {
            // get any key from user to exit program
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            anotherGame = "n";
            Console.WriteLine(anotherGame);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid input (Y/N) only!");
        }
    } while(anotherGame != "y" && anotherGame != "n")
    return anotherGame;
}
```

Comment: If you're using the while loop there's no reason for the recursive call to `promptRedo`.

Comment: @Rotem I have already delete that line. as I had copied the OP's code, I had forgotton to delete it. Thanks.

Comment: Even better would be to declare anotherGame and the function  as a boolean

Answer (score 0):

you haven't assigned the of "promptRedo(anotherGame)" method to "anotherGame" variable in else block.

Instead of:

```
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid input (Y/N) only!");
        promptRedo(anotherGame);
    }
```

you should write:

```
     else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Invalid input (Y/N) only!");
        anotherGame = promptRedo(anotherGame);
    }
```